# UPDATE and INSERT in other table with MERGE when matched statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I googled this topic for some type of help/answers, but I didn't find much. I'm asking because I prefer `MERGE`; if not possible, then I'll go back to the regular Updates/Inserts.

I have two tables: `[Course]` and `[CourseHistory]`. Both have three columns: `EmpId`, `CourseId`, `CourseName`. The following `MERGE` statement works correctly in the sense that it `UPDATEs` or `INSERTs` to `[Course]` when it has to.

What I need to include is to insert into `[CourseHistory]` when there's an `UPDATE`. Essentially, I will be backing up the record that will be about to be modified.

I tried including a *sort of* `INSERT` statement, but I get syntax errors.

My tsql statement looks like the following:

```
merge dbo.Courses as pre              
using (select @EmpId as EmpId, @CourseId as CourseId) as S              
    on  pre.EmpId = S.EmpId and pre.CourseId = s.CourseId
  when matched then
   /* 
     INSERT INTO [CourseHistory] (EmpId, CourseId, CourseName)
     SELECT EmpId, CourseId, CourseName 
     where EmpId = @EmpId and @CourseId = CourseId
   */
    update set
        CourseName = @CourseName
  when not matched then              
    INSERT (CourseId, EmpId, CourseName)
    VALUES (@CourseId, @EmpId, @CourseName);
```

Comment: Have you rejected using a trigger on `Courses` to maintain `CourseHistory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I've updated my answer based on  rbhatup bellow comment.

I would use [OUTPUT ... INTO ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause with `$action` virtual column thus:

```
-- It create a temp. table with the same columns and data type like source table
SELECT TOP(0) *, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), N'') AS MergeAction 
INTO #AffectedRows 
FROM dbo.Courses;
-- If source table have one column with IDENTOTY property then this SELECT INTO will add also the IDENTITY property to the same column

MERGE... your statement ...
OUTPUT deleted.*, $action into  #AffectedRows; -- deleted = old values, inserted = new values

INSERT INTO [CourseHistory] -- You could add a new column to CourseHistory named [Action] (will store values from MergeAction)
SELECT * FROM #AffectedRows r
WHERE r.MergeAction = 'UPDATE'
```

Comment: Thanks. Considering that these tables tend to change, is it possible to _output_ the output to a`#temp table` instead of a `@table variable`? That way I don't need to declare it at the top of the stored procedure. I searched, but all the examples use `@tables`

Comment: If `[Course]` and `[CourseHistory]` were to change such that using a table variable was a problem, then you would need to change your Merge statement anyway.  So I don't see how using a temp table would make a difference.  However, yes, you could use this syntax with a temp table instead of a table variable.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: Target table (user table, temp table, table variable) of `OUTPUT ... INTO <target table>` must exist before INSERT.

Comment: I really don't understand why you're using `#temp` here. Seems crazy. The inserts will be persistent in this global temporary table, which will then cause problems on subsequent calls. Also, if I recall correctly, `@tables` are faster than `#temp tables`.

Comment: See first comment, second phrase. Then that might highlight a problem, but not for me. There is no global temp table in my answer, please be careful. Wrong: shortest correct answer is [here] "it depends" (few quick tips: table variables doesn't have column statistics and - till SQL2012 SP2 - doesn't cause recompilations - these can be good or [bad !](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952444) - it depends).